# AWS pre processing Cloudformation stack error : Policy assignment error causing rollback

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, shell

Itis my first time attempting to create a ML model ... its been a rough ride ... here is the error that I am getting...

```
Policy arn:aws:iam::796406704065:policy/AWSDataExchangeService does not exist or is not attachable. (Service: AmazonIdentityManagement; Status Code: 404; Error Code: NoSuchEntity; Request ID: d1f4cbbb-0386-4a6a-a025-cf2614d68f9a; Proxy: null)
```

rollback_complete error status
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9wQK2.jpg

the policy in question is the AWSDataExchangeService
I have created the policy that would grant the the script access it needs and it appears it does not matter... as it searches for the policy at a specific arn, this arn appears to not exist anymore

I cannot move forward without this step in the pre processing